# Changed my page tab app to 810 width, only changed on app page, not users'

Tags: width, facebook-page

Yesterday morning, we changed our page tab app to use the wider 810 pixel width as described on this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

If I go to our app and view the demo, the width change has occurred. However, on all our users' pages, including one that just added the app about 30 minutes ago, the narrow 520 width persists.

Does this take a week to change on everyone's pages or is something wrong?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Maybe you should link to your app canvas page so we can see if it's something in your source, or if the problem is showing up for others besides yourself... It could be a caching problem, or that the change hasn't propagated to all the FB servers yet, or you're missing something in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a setting in `Advanced Settings` called `Page Tab iframe`.
Setting this to `enabled` fixes the problem.

Still looking for the reasoning why this setting only appears on some apps but not all.

Comment: @hjuster this option no longer appears.